# What wallets currently support RBF?

Tags: wallet, replace-by-fee

What wallets currently support RBF? 
Is there some workaround if they don't?

Comment: Friends a little what you mean by support. You mean you want to create RBF transactions? Or do you mean they need to recognise incoming RBF transactions and then do something special with them (user interface warning). I've heard greenaddress supports RBF, not sure and don't know about others.

Answer (score 4):

No wallet currently supports creating replaceable transactions conveniently. To work around this, you can manually create raw transactions from scratch.

The following are suggested instructions for use with bitcoin-cli.

To create a replaceable transaction. You can use "createrawtransaction" to manually add inputs and mark the "nsequence" field to a value less than 0xffffffff. If you would like to replace the first transaction created this way. You will have to dump the transaction to free the UTXOs for use again using the "abandontransaction" command.

Once you've dumped the first transaction. You should be able to repeat the process above then increment the "nsequence" field. This new transaction when broadcasted should then be accepted by any node that supports full RBF.

Comment: This answer is outdated, please consider updating it. :)

Answer (score 3):

As I answered in another question, Electrum Bitcoin Wallet has the feature. I've confirmed that mac client worked. It seems that Android app has the same feature.

https://electrum.org/#download

[Which clients offer a way to replace unconfirmed transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22699/which-clients-offer-a-way-to-replace-unconfirmed-transactions/52932#52932)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know other than bitcoin core API's (as renlord [suggested](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/44524/14871)) the only wallet that conveniently supports the functionality is [GreenAddress](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/greenaddress-is-first-bitcoin-wallet-to-launch-replace-by-fee-bitcoin-transactions-miner-adoption-slow-1463516896)

Answer (score 0):

Today, Bitcoin Core, Electrum, Blockstream Green, and Samourai support creating [BIP125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki) opt-in full RBF transactions. These wallets then subsequently allow bumping the feerate of transactions signalling replaceability.

The Bitcoin Optech group [tracks](https://bitcoinops.org/en/compatibility/#replace-by-fee-rbf) RBF capability of wallets and services in their compatibility matrix.